# NSURLConnection (as part of AFNetworking) doesn't call NSURLConnectionDataDelegate delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

## The Issue

I am using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/), which generates an NSURLConnection object, to upload a photo.

The NSURLConnection is not making any calls to the

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

method. (It's part of the [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html), defined in NSURLConnection.h)

The request is an HTTP POST request with a photo attachment (Content-Disposition "form-data", Mime type "image/jpeg").  This should (I think) result in periodic calls to this method as the upload progresses.

I need the method to display a progress bar to the user.  However, the method is not getting called.

Note:

- The delegate is set properly; other delegate methods are called
- The file upload is successful

## AFNetworking Code

I'm pretty sure this is an NSURLConnection issue, not an AFNetworking issue.

But just in case, here is the relevant code from my `AFHTTPClient` subclass:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:constructor];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];

if (constructor) {
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];
}

[self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

My AFHTTPClient subclass does NOT override ANY of the methods I am calling:

- `multipartFormRequestWithMethod: path: parameters: constructingBodyWithBlock:`
- `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest: success: failure:`
- `setUploadProgressBlock:`
- `enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:`

`constructor` is a block with type `(void (^)(id<AFMultipartFormData>))` and is not `nil` (verified by stepping through code).

When I type `po operation.uploadProgress` in the debugger, I see `$0 = 0x1301d9f0 <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x1301d9f0>` so I think the block is being set correctly.

The file always uploads successfully, but the code in the upload progress block is not run, so my progress bar never updates.

## Questions

Why isn't NSURLConnection calling this method?

What are the circumstances in which NSURLConnection is supposed to?  (It doesn't appear to be well-documented.)

And most importantly, how can I display the upload progress to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library maybe implements a `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` method in a category on `NSObject`. That would be very nasty but that could explain why the method of `AFURLConnectionOperation` is not called.

In order to check this assumption, you can run [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) on your compiled binary.  Search for `didSendBodyData:` in the output. If there’s a match in a category, the library is clearly responsible. The library could also be messing with the Objective-C runtime, but that would be harder to detect than just running class-dump.

Comment: `class-dump --arch armv7 MyFile` says "File doesn't contain the specified architecture (armv7).  Available architectures are armv7, armv7s, i386."  But running `file MyFile` indicates armv7, i386, and "cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)".

Comment: The error message is unfortunately misleading (it’s on my TODO list to fix it). You must run class-dump on your **application** binary, not on the **library** binary.

Answer (score 3):

A third-party error reporting library was overriding that delegate method on NSURLConnection.  Removing the library resolved the issue.  (There was no issue with either AFNetworking or NSURLConnection.)

If you can provide troubleshooting steps that would have isolated this issue faster, I will award the bounty to you.  (Keep in mind that the third-party library is compiled, so a source code search wouldn't have worked.)

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what third party library is causing your issue so that we can avoid it and also investigate what it's doing to try to answer your troubleshooting steps question?

Comment: @0xced I can't say what the library is because it's not yet open to the public. Is the only way to override a delegate method like that to implement it as a category?  If not, what are the other ways? How could I determine if another class is doing this?

Comment: @AaronBrager Categories can [invoke the supersequent implementation](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) of the original method.